# how to slice php array

Tags: php, arrays, slice

what i want to do is that i am creating php array dynamic .i dont know about the elements in the array. lets say i have array like this

```
$mix_array =array('1','3','6','1','5','3','6','5','1','7','3','9');
```

i want slicing of this array.i want to create arrays from the above array but of common elements like

```
$array_1 = ('1','1','1');
$array_2 = ('3','3','3');
$array_3 = ('6','6');
$array_4 = ('5','5');
$array_5 = ('9');
$array_6 = ('7');
```

that is first find common elements in original array and make other  array from that

Comment: array_slice(), trying intersect but not well enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, here is an example (by the way, quite inefficient, but enough if it is a short work):

```
<?php
$mix_array = array('1','3','6','1','5','3','6','5','1','7','3','9');
$sliced_array = array();

foreach($mix_array as $k => $v) {
    if( count($sliced_array[$v]) > 0 ) {
        array_push($sliced_array[$v], $v);
    } else {
        $sliced_array[$v] = array($v);
    }
}
?>
```

You should take a look at http://es.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 2):

Better make assosative array instead of typing `$array_1`, `$array_2`. And instead of making array with same values like `array('1', '1', '1')`, you can just keep the amount of value like `array('1' => 3)`

```
$mix_array = array ('1','3','6','1','5','3','6','5','1','7','3','9');
$group_array = array();
foreach ($mix_array as $value) {
    if(isset($group_array[$value])) {
        $group_array[$value]++;
    }
    else {
        $group_array[$value] = 1;
    }
}

print_r($group_array);
```

Result

```
Array
(
[1] => 3
[3] => 3
[6] => 2
[5] => 2
[7] => 1
[9] => 1
)
```

Or as Josh said simply use `array_count_values()`

Comment: A native function already exists for this, [`array_count_values($arr)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_count_values`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) for this:

```
$array = array_count_values($mix_array);
/* $array will have the following content:
   $array{
       1 => 3
       3 => 3
       6 => 2
     ...
*/
```

If you really need the sliced version, then you can use [`array_fill`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

```
$result = array();
$i = 0;
for($array as $key=>$value)
    $result[$i++] = array_fill(0,$value,$key);
/* $result[0] = (1,1,1),
   $result[1] = (3,3,3),
     ...
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

array_slice() // http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

or

array_chunk() // http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php